# Register a C#/VB.NET COM dll programmatically

Tags: c#, vb.net, com, dll, com-interop

Question: I have a .NET dll which I use from a C++ program.
Now I have to register the dll programmatically on a deployment computer.

How do I do that (programmatically! not using regasm)? 
I remember, when I once called a VB6 dll from a C++ dll, I had to use DllRegisterServer and DllUnregisterServer.

Is that still so with a .NET dll?
It seems I have to somehow add the dllregisterserver function to the .NET dll.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

YUK, .NET dlls don't have DllRegisterServer, so you have to write a .NET installer, executing this somewhere:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile (@"c:\temp\ImageConverter.dll");
RegistrationServices regAsm = new RegistrationServices();
bool bResult = regAsm.RegisterAssembly(asm, AssemblyRegistrationFlags.SetCodeBase);
```

Comment: AFAIK it needs administrator rights. Not a big difference with calling `regasm` directly. But it works. +1

Comment: @Arnaud Bouchez: One big difference: You can put a try - catch around it, and handle errors. As with spawning a new process, it's also possible, but a lot more work.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use [process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see what system changes (basically registry changes I think) are made when you use `regasm.exe` to register your dll, and then make those changes programatically instead?

Comment: Yes, that's the way to go with pure C/C++. Nice, but I think it might take time to figure out how to get the data to write there...