# Register .NET COM DLL file on a client machine

Tags: asp.net, dll, asp-classic, com, com+

I need inputs on:

I've created a DLL file using .NET. This DLL file is intended to use for [ASP Classic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages) and ASP.NET applications. I've created a setup and deployment package, and I added the solution's output to [GAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache) folder. After that, creating an instance in ASP Classic didn't work. I am not sure, if it can load from the GAC folder.

Alternatively, I converted this .dll as COM by adding inheriting from ServiceComponent and other necessary changes, but while registering on client as COM, it throws an error:

> one or more files do not contain components or type libraries

What am I missing? What shall I do so that the DLL file can be used by ASP Classic and ASP.NET?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378730/register-a-c-vb-net-com-dll-programatically

Answer (score 2):

Steps...

```
Visual studio: start a new class library
Properties > Application : make assembly COM-Visible
Properties > Build : Register for COM interop
Properties > Signing: Sign the assembly
```

Then build the project.

Start the Visual Studio command prompt as administrator (look in the OS menu for this one):

```
cd <path to your dll>
RegAsm /register <name of your dll>.dll /tlb:<name of your dll>.tlb
gacutil -i <name of your dll>.dll
IISreset (not a bad idea to reset after these stepts in your development environment because the dll gets cached)
```

That should do the trick...

One last word of advice... Build a new project from scratch (just an Hello World) and get the above steps in your DNA. This is one of those areas where ... it works - noop, it doesn't - and now it works again plays a big role ;-)

Comment: Hmm Ok. I will try advice to build a new project from scratch. How will I deploy this dll as COM on client? will I be able to load .net dll put in gac in classic asp?

Comment: I've deployed by copy-ing the dll to the target machine and run the regasm and the gactutil on the target machine. Don't know if you have those tools on your target machine. Probably you will be able to build a setup, but I've no experience by building such a setup.

Comment: I created solution from scratch and were able to host as COM component. I am able to use this COM developed in .net in class asp but same is not working in asp.net. In my local dev box, I see my component under COM tab but path shows .tbl file not dll in VS2010. What shall I do so that this COM component can also be used in asp.net by adding a reference? Do I put dll in GAC or system32 via installation?

Comment: am getting this error when adding .tlb ref: a reference to could not be added. converting the type library to a .net assembly failed.