# .NET Interop 'Method not found: 'Void System.Threading.Monitor.Enter..

Tags: .net, delphi, interop

A partner created a COM lib x.dll and x.tlb in C#, with .NET framework 4. He had the "Com Interop" checkbox checked in VS.

He then referred to this [Register a C#/VB.NET COM dll programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378730/register-a-c-vb-net-com-dll-programatically) to create a tool that registers the .dll. It worked. (Our Delphi app can access the .COM object) The code he used to register (from the above link) is:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile (@"c:\temp\x.dll");
RegistrationServices regAsm = new RegistrationServices();
bool bResult = regAsm.RegisterAssembly(asm, AssemblyRegistrationFlags.SetCodeBase);
```

We imported the x.tlb into Delphi 7, creating a .pas file through which we are making calls to the COM library.

In Delphi, when we call a function in the COM library, we're getting an error:

```
...exception class EOleException with message 'Method not found: 'Void
 System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(System.Object, Boolean ByRef)''. Process stopped.
```

We have no idea what this means or how to resolve it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Somehow it is using .NET of a previous version. Is there a setting somewhere to set the target platform?

Comment: @LURD It is at compile time, when you create the C# .dll, that you can specify the expected .NET version.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez, yes that was what I meant.

Comment: @LURD If you post that as an answer, I'll flag it as such. Thank you. Our build process will inadvertently including a version targeted for the wrong platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When compiling the C# dll, it is targeting a .NET version prior to framework 4.

Make sure the setting in the compiler is targeting the correct platform version.