# Create object library for Excel vba

Tags: c#, vba, excel

I have a GUI I wrote in C#. It's a grid of interactive buttons and text that controls a register map. I would like to create an API for that GUI to use in Excel vba. I have been unable to find any examples or documentation for how to create such a thing, but I have used other companies' object libraries before.

In my attempt to create this, I have ran into some problems, namely **it only works on my computer**. Also, if I move to another folder on my computer, it also breaks.

Excel vba Code:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim impclass As New ZZVISIBLE_FROM_EXCEL_CLASS
    MsgBox impclass.DotNetMethod_SQR(5)
End Sub
```

C# Library Class Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ZZVISIBLE_FROM_EXCEL_LIBRARY
{
    public class ZZVISIBLE_FROM_EXCEL_CLASS
    {
        public Double DotNetMethod_SQR(Double input)
        {
            return input * input;
        }
    }
}
```

This foundational example uses C# library class to square a number and Excel VBA to choose the number 5. This is a basic framework for later things I wish to do such as:

`grid.writecell(22,1001)`

`grid.getcell(22)`

`grid.resetall()`

`grid.loadfile("C:\griddata\config_default")`

[image]

Some references for making these object libraries or even what they are called would be most helpful! Googling "custom excel vba references in C#" has led to nothing useful so far, so I decided to post here for help.

Also, I'm early enough in the project that "you're doing it wrong, do this" type answers are welcomed as well!

Comment: can you not do the same thing in C# using `Microsoft.Interop.Excel` have you tried to google examples on using Interop..?

Comment: This is a great comment! Unfortunately the reason I am doing it this way is to maintain compatibility with code written in Excel VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to know the dotnet version you are working on so you use either  :
        C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\regasm.exe 
        or c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe

Second you need to know whether you want to register the dlls as 32 bit or 64 bit so use the same previous path for 32 bit or just use  Framework64 instead of Framework in case of 64 bit

once done you can add reference to this assembly in easily in your vba script like that :
                                  [image]

once added you can instantiate any intance of any class exists in the dll

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of choices:

1) Create an assembly and make it COM visible using regasm

See article on CodeProject

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/555660/Extend-your-VBA-code-with-Csharp-VB-NET-or-Cpluspl

2) To make a C# assembly visible to Excel you have to make it COM visible and set the ReferenceAssemblyFromVbaProject to true.

Please see the following MSDN article for more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608604.aspx

Thanks, Kevin

Comment: Good advice, but it didn't fix the issue of deployment. Only my computer runs it. How am I supposed to deploy this as a tool other people can use?

Comment: @SwimBikeRun the answer is right there - use `regasm` to register the `.dll` and `.tlb` on other machines. Before deploying make sure you are targeting the correct platform.

Comment: As vba4all said you can use regasm, you could also write a .NET Installer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378730/register-a-c-vb-net-com-dll-programatically You will need admin privileges either way.

Comment: The problem is that the target machines need this regasm tool, which means they must install visual studio...

Comment: Thanks for the .NET installer link

Comment: I take it you found out that regasm is located in a folder similar to: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727

Comment: Ah no I didn't. Thanks!

Comment: Now I have a C# library function that I can call in vba. How do I make aspects of my C# GUI go into this C# library?

Comment: @SwimBikeRun - I think that is a question for another thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your library in an [Excel-DNA](http://excel-dna.net) add-in. ([Excel-DNA](http://excel-dna.net) is a free library I develop for integrating .NET with Excel). This may ease registration issues with COM (allowing you to deploy the COM object mode without requiring administrator permissions).

It will also help if you want to expose some functionality as user-defined function that you can call from the worksheet in Excel, add a ribbon or anything like that.

For using Excel-DNA to expose an object model to VBA, I suggest these posts by [Mikael Katajamäki](http://mikejuniperhill.blogspot.com) as a starting point:

- http://mikejuniperhill.blogspot.com/2014/03/interfacing-c-and-vba-with-exceldna-no.html
- http://mikejuniperhill.blogspot.com/2014/03/interfacing-c-and-vba-with-exceldna_16.html

For general Excel-DNA support I suggest you use the [Excel-DNA Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/exceldna).